# stringByAppendingPathComponent: in Xcode 7 beta 5

Tags: ios, xcode, nsstring, xcode7, xcode7-beta5

In the latest build of Xcode 7 (beta 5), the NSString method stringByAppendingPathComponent: has been entirely removed. This had been incredibly useful when working with file paths

Is there a new method to replace this or achieve similar functionality?

Comment: This may help: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13580

Seems people are just switching to URL rather than path or using an extension.

Answer (score 0):

It removed to NSURL, you can use this:

```
  NSURL(string: yourPath)!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent)
```

or for most compability

```
 NSString(string: yourPath).stringByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent)
```